# Need more memory in micromax Canvas colors 2

Tags: insufficient-memory, storage, micromax

I have my one year old model of  micromax Canvas colors 2. As many of you may know, it has limited internal memory, So I cannot install app which are only stores in phone memory. I have to install so limited apps on my phones due to this drawback. Can anyone tell me how can I solve this issue?

Comment: I suggest starting with our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info), which contains several hints/links on exactly this topic. Then come back here and either [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) (if you found a solution), or [edit] your question with what you've tried and where you're stuck. Note that not all hardware limitations can be overcome, so the only real solution might be buying a "better device".

Comment: Right Izzy, agreed with you about hardware limitation , but I thought there may be some 'tricky' tools which can be helpful.

Comment: Those you might find using the mentioned tag-wiki as starting point :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your device rooted ? If it is you can use link2sd it can increase internal memory by adding an SD card.

If it's not there are many apps that you can move to SD without any program in settings.

Comment: I will try your first solution, For 2nd, It is only useful if app can be installed in SDcard, Where I am blocked.